# ByRef seems to receive the value and not the reference in VBA 6.0

Tags: vba, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

My little sample code

```
Function AddNr(ByRef x As Integer) As Integer
    x = x + 2
    AddNr = x
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim ana As Integer
    ana = 1
    AddNr (ana)
    MsgBox ana
End Sub
```

should output 3 but outputs 1. To be more specific the `ana` variable is not modified after the call to the `AddNr` function.

My environment is Microsoft Visual Basic 6.5 inside Excel 2007.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should be:

```
 AddNr ana
```

That is, no brackets.

From Microsoft Help:

> Remarks
>
> You are not required to use the Call
>   keyword when calling a procedure.
>   However, if you use the Call keyword
>   to call a procedure that requires
>   arguments, argumentlist must be
>   enclosed in parentheses. If you omit
>   the Call keyword, you also must omit
>   the parentheses around argumentlist.
>   If you use either Call syntax to call
>   any intrinsic or user-defined
>   function, the function's return value
>   is discarded.

Answer (score 10):

Remou nailed it already, but I thought the role of parentheses in function calls could be fleshed out a bit.  Adding an *extra* set of parentheses to an argument in a procedure call forces that argument to be passed by value, regardless of whether the called procedure wants the argument by reference or by value.  The official help page from Microsoft on this topic is here: [How to: Force an Argument to Be Passed by Value (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chy4288y.aspx).

The concept is most easily explained by an example:

```
Sub Foo(ByRef Bar)
    Bar = 1
End Sub

Sub TestFoo()
Dim Bar
    Bar = 0
    Foo Bar   'The variable Bar is passed ByRef to Foo
    Debug.Print Bar '--> 1

    Bar = 0
    Foo (Bar)  'The expression (Bar) is evaluated and 
               '  the resultant value 0 is passed ByVal to Foo
    Debug.Print Bar '--> 0

    Bar = 0
    Call Foo(Bar)  'The variable Bar is passed ByRef to Foo
    Debug.Print Bar '--> 1

    Bar = 0
    Call Foo((Bar))  'The expression (Bar) is evaluated and 
                     '  the resultant value 0 is passed ByVal to Foo
    Debug.Print Bar '--> 0
End Sub
```