# Several If Statements in an access 2007 vba subroutine. Curious if there is another way?

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, vba

First let me premise with I am very new to access vba.

My question is I have several if then else statements in a row for example

```
If Me.txtRevenuePerHour.Value < 90 Then
    Me.chkRPH.Value = -1
    Me.chkRPH.Enabled = "False"
End If

If Me.txtLoadTime.Value < 0.25 Then
    Me.chkLT15.Value = -1
    Me.chkLT15.Enabled = "False"
End If
```

I was wondering if there is another way besides rewriting the if statements over and over again.  If not then I will accept that but just curious if there is another way.

The if statements check a checkbox control if certain conditions are met.  Most are different conditions but some are the same

Thank you ahead of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for each if uses completely different objects and conditions in the `If` clause and inside the `If` blocks different objects are used as well.

There is no way to generalize the `If` itself, thought the body of the `If` may be:

Untested code:

```
Sub DisableAndSetToMinusOne(ctrl As Control)
  ctrl.Value = -1
  ctrl.Enabled = "False"
End Sub


If Me.txtRevenuePerHour.Value < 90 Then
    DisableAndSetToMinusOne(Me.chkRPH)
End If

If Me.txtLoadTime.Value < 0.25 Then
    DisableAndSetToMinusOne(Me.chkLT15)
End If
```

Comment: I tried the code that you gave to me and it bombed out in the top line of the sub

Comment: It highlighted the (Control ctrl) area so I think it had something to do with that

Comment: @Max gay - apologies, my C# contaminated the code... try my edited code.

Comment: I am surprised this runs because in VBA you need to add Call if you are using brackets `Call DisableAndSetToMinusOne(Me.chkLT15)`. It is more usual to just omit the brackets `DisableAndSetToMinusOne Me.chkLT15` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876524/byref-seems-to-receive-the-value-and-not-the-reference-in-vba-6-0). `False` is not usually quoted, but you can get away with it.