# Object Required error Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a VBA application, and I have the following code:

---

```
Dim previousCell As range


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As range)

Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error GoTo ws_exit:


Set previousCell = target
getEffort (previousCell) '**Here i get object required** 

ws_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub

Private Function getEffort(ByVal cell As range)

' do soemthing

End Sub
```

I'm not sure why I get the error message:  `Object required error at getEffort(previousCell)`. If I pass in the `Target`, it works.

Thanks

Comment: Should _Private Function_ be _Private Sub_ since you are not concerned with getting a value returned and Private Function ends with "END SUB"?

Comment: Don't use parentheses when calling getEffort.  If you use parentheses then your code will be expecting a return value (does getEffort return anything?)

Comment: Note: you can use parantheses if you type `Call` before the sub name - `Call getEffort(previousCell)`

Answer (score 18):

As others have suggested, the problem is the parentheses.  What no one has adequately explained is why it is the parentheses.

When you say this:

```
getEffort previousCell
```

Then you are passing the `previousCell` **Range object** into the getEffort procedure.  That is what the procedure expects and so it is happy.

When you say this:

```
getEffort (previousCell)
```

The parentheses around `previousCell` cause VBA to *evaluate* the `previousCell` object.  When VBA *evaluates* an object it returns that object's default property.  The default property of the Range object is `.Value`, which is a string.

So previousCell is evaluated and a **string** gets passed on to getEffort.  Of course getEffort is expecting a Range object, so you receive the error message.

The fact that you are assigning `Target` to `previousCell` is a red herring.  You likely introduced the parentheses when you switched to `previousCell`.  If you don't believe me, try this:

```
getEffort (Target)
```

You will get the same error message.

Comment: For additional information, see my answer to a different question: [ByRef seems to receive the value and not the reference in VBA 6.0](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4877030/154439)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like target is not set to an instance of an object which is giving you the error. when you pass in the target the argument to the function function(argument) is set to an instance of an object. when you set previouscell = target target actually needs to be something or else you will get the exec error.

try setting previouscell = ActiveCell

Answer (score 0):

Two things: first, you need to not use `()` or include some sort of return value when calling getEffort as a function. You also need to determine if you want that to be a sub/function, right now you are using both. Presumably you are making it a sub?

```
Dim previousCell As range


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As range)

Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error GoTo ws_exit:


Set previousCell = target
getEffort previousCell '**Here i get object required** 
'or...
call getEffort(previousCell)

'add this too..
'exit sub
ws_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub

Private sub getEffort(ByVal cell As range)

' do soemthing

End sub
```

---

Also, your main program never exits before your error statement, so it will pop up that message box always. Try adding `Exit Sub` before the error label to avoid a blank message box always appearing.